# Can not find soomla example project

Tags: unity-game-engine, soomla

Where can I find example project with Soomla framework?
The one I can open in Unity and see how it works.
Soomla knowledge base doesn't help at all.

Maybe there is one in unity assets store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this project provided by Spartonix (not by SOOMLA) is your best bet.
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/31343

Comment: Maybe you have a link with Soomla Level Up as well?

Answer (score 0):

These two may be able to help. They are getting a bit dated though.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rkflG8RdiU0&list=PLi8OcITs56tMoZg191ZjKcZpxmzO5wBZ-

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3u3Q4WEEEkc&list=PLi8OcITs56tOj2ZNOmYRIrBIxkVecodth